# using mutate_if() to convert S3: POSIXct variables to character (chr) variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am wondering why the following `dplyr::mutate_if()` doesn't work?

1. Create `flights_df` with dates in `S3: POSIXct` format as done [here](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/dates-and-times.html#creating-datetimes)

   `` flights <- nycflights13::flights
   make_datetime_100 <- function(year, month, day, time) {
    make_datetime(year, month, day, time %/% 100, time %% 100)
   }
   flights_df <- flights %>%
    sample_n(100) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(dep_time), !is.na(arr_time)) %>%
    mutate(
         dep_time = make_datetime_100(year, month, day, dep_time),
         arr_time = make_datetime_100(year, month, day, arr_time),
         sched_dep_time = make_datetime_100(year, month, day, sched_dep_time),
         sched_arr_time = make_datetime_100(year, month, day, sched_arr_time)) %>%
     dplyr::select(origin, dest, ends_with("delay"), ends_with("time"))` ``

Now use `mutate_if()` to convert dates to characters as seen [here](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html)

`flights_df %>% as_tibble() %>% mutate_if(is.Date, as.character)`

Answer (score 2):

You are dealing with POSIXct / xt objects.

`class(flights_df$arr_time[1])
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"`

Your conversion works if you use is.POSIXct

`flights_df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate_if(is.POSIXct, as.character)`